# In Java, how would I make a class that is essentially a subclass of string, but sets an allowable length range?

Tags: java, inheritance, static, subclass, final

I'm trying to make a new object type which is intended to act like a subclass of String. I'm aware a class cannot extend String. I'm making application that has requirements such as a Contact's first name cannot be longer than 10 characters, and cannot be null, the last name cannot be more than 15 characters.

I started off making the class like so:

```
package Models;

/**
 * @author Charles Hilton
 *
 */
public class LimitedString {
    private String value;
    private static final String descriptor;
    private static final Integer minimumLength;
    private static final Integer maximumLength;
    private static final boolean nullable;
    
    public LimitedString(String value, String descriptor, Integer maximumLength, Integer minimumLength, boolean isNullable) throws Exception {
        if (minimumLength < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minimum length cannot be less than 0");
        }
        if (minimumLength > maximumLength) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minimum length cannot be greater than maximum length");
        }
        this.minimumLength = minimumLength;
        this.maximumLength = maximumLength;
        this.nullable = isNullable;
        this.descriptor = descriptor;   // i.e. descriptor = "Contact First Name"
        this.setValue(value);
    }
    
    LimitedString(String descriptor, Integer maximumLength, Integer minimumLength, boolean isNullable) {
        if (minimumLength < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minimum length cannot be less than 0");
        }
        if (minimumLength > maximumLength) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minimum length cannot be greater than maximum length");
        }
        this.minimumLength = minimumLength;
        this.maximumLength = maximumLength;
        this.nullable = isNullable;
        this.descriptor = descriptor;   // i.e. descriptor = "Contact First Name"
        this.setValue(value);
    }

    public String ToString() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        if (value == null && !nullable) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value cannot be null.");
        if (value.length() < minimumLength || value.length() > maximumLength) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("@s must be between %s character(s) and %s characters long.", descriptor, minimumLength, maximumLength));
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static String getDescriptor() {
        return descriptor;
    }

    public static Integer getMinimumlength() {
        return minimumLength;
    }

    public static Integer getMaximumlength() {
        return maximumLength;
    }

    public static boolean isNullable() {
        return nullable;
    }
    
}
```

then using it in a Contact class like so:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package Models;

/**
 * @author Charles Hilton
 *
 */
public class Contact {
    private LimitedString firstName = new LimitedString("First Name", 10, 1, false);
    private LimitedString lastName = new LimitedString("Last Name", 15, 1, false);
    
    private Contact() {};
    
    public Contact(String lastName, String firstName) {
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.getValue();
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.setValue(firstName);
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.getValue();
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.setValue(lastName);
    }
}
```

I'm worried that it could be optimized better. For starters, in LimitedString. I made several fields static and final with the intention of trying to minimize memory usage as more contacts are added to a collection, which I apparently can't do the way I have it setup right now.

Answer (score 3):

## `CharSequence`

To directly answer your question, I suggest writing a class that implements the [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface. `String`, `StringBuilder`, and some other classes implement that interface.

If you want to be able to add more text to an existing object of your class, your class should also implement [`Appendable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Appendable.html).

I imagine your class would contain a `String`. If appendable, perhaps a `StringBuilder`.

I don’t see the need for your `descriptor` field.

Rather than carry a `nullable` field, consider writing two classes. One is a subclass of the other, one tolerating a null, the other not.

## *Jakarta Bean Validation*

A better solution to needs like null-checks, and like limiting the size of a field, is [*Jakarta Bean Validation*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation). See [specification page](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/); [Version 3](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/) is current. See [project page](https://beanvalidation.org/) (a bit outdated).

Some validators are [provided](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/jakarta-bean-validation-spec-3.0.html#builtinconstraints). And you can write your own validators.

You can invoke validators in your code. And the validators can be invoked by a user-interface built in [*JavaFX*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) or built in [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow_(Java_API)).

I believe that the provided validators `NotNull` and `Size` would accomplish your goals. But `NotBlank` is better than `NotNull` as it also checks that the non-null text contains at least one non-whitespace character.

```
@NotBlank 
@Size( min=1 , max=10 )  
private String firstName ;
```

Comment: Thank you, Basil. I've tried implementing Jakarta Validation in an Eclipse Maven project and applied the mentioned annotations to the fields, but it doesn't seem to work as intended. Running a simple program that creates an object, with arguments that would violate the constraints doesn't yield an error. Is it intended to be used with a REST application?

Comment: @CharlesHilton If executing outside of a context that auto-invokes validation such as CDI, then you must programmatically invoke a validation. See section 1.3, [*Validating constraints*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_validating_constraints) of the Hibernate Validator 8 guide. Notice the calls to `validator.validate( car )`. That is what I meant by “You can invoke validators in your code.” in my Answer.